Extend TypedDict to save/retrieve as JSON to/from file
I want to have simple data structure, and save it to disk as JSON, and later take the JSON and put back into the data structure.
This is the error I get:

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'saveToFile'

with the code below:
import json
from typing_extensions import TypedDict

class AutoBlog(TypedDict):
    blog_title: str
    blog_prompt: str
    min_words: int
    max_words: int
    def saveToFile(self, filename):
        str_json = json.dumps(self)
        with open(filename, 'w', encoding='unicode-escape') as f:
            f.write(str_json)
    def readFromFile(self, filename):
        with open(filename) as f:
            str_json = f.read()
        self = json.loads(str_json)
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        filename = 'c:/Users/All Users/WebsiteGarden/test_serialize.json'
        print("Filename=" + filename)
    
        autoBlogData1 = AutoBlog()
        autoBlogData1['blog_title'] = "my blog title"
        autoBlogData1['blog_prompt'] = "write an article about xyz"
        autoBlogData1['min_words'] = 800
        autoBlogData1['max_words'] = 1200
    
        autoBlogData1.saveToFile(filename)
    
        autoBlogData2 = AutoBlog()
        autoBlogData2.readFromFile(filename)
        print("autoBlogData2['blog_title']=" + autoBlogData2['blog_title'])


TypedDicts can't have extra methods, they're just a way to describe the shape of a dictionary: https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#rejected-alternatives. Maybe you want a dataclass, or a custom Mapping.

I know it's been some time but I have another solution for you. From what I understood, you were trying to have a dict with specific key values that you could write as JSON to a file and read as JSON from a file. Also the key values looked like they could be Python identifiers (like variable names). Let me know if I have not grasped what you were trying to do.
Instead of using a subclass of dict, I would propose that you use a class with slots. This way you may limit this instance's variables to what has been defined in the class definition.
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound='AutoBlog')

@dataclass(slots=True)
class AutoBlog:
    # If you don't provide default values here you will be 
    # forced to provide values when creating a new instance
    blog_title: str = ""        # default value: empty string
    blog_prompt: str = ""       # default value: empty string
    min_words: int = 0          # default value: 0
    max_words: int = 2000       # default value: 2000

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls: type[T], input_dict: dict) -> T:
        input_dict_filtered = {
            key: value for key, value in input_dict.items() 
            if key in cls.__slots__
        }
        return cls(**input_dict_filtered)
    
    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        return {key: getattr(self, key) for key in self.__slots__}

    def save_to_file(self, filename: str) -> None:
        with open(filename, 'w') as output_file:
            json.dump(self.to_dict(), output_file)
    
    @classmethod
    def read_from_file(cls: type[T], filename: str) -> T:
        with open(filename) as input_file:
            input_json = json.load(input_file)
        return cls.from_dict(input_json)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "test_serialize.json"
    print("Filename=" + filename)

    auto_blog_data1 = AutoBlog(
        blog_title="my blog title",
        blog_prompt="write an article about xyz",
        min_words=800,
        max_words=1200
    )

    auto_blog_data1.save_to_file(filename)

    auto_blog_data2 = AutoBlog.read_from_file(filename)

    print(f"auto_blog_data2.blog_title = {auto_blog_data2.blog_title}")

    # This part will only work if you have defined default values
    # for this class 
    auto_blog_data3 = AutoBlog()
    auto_blog_data3.blog_title = "my other blog title"
    auto_blog_data3.blog_prompt = "Write another inspired article"
    auto_blog_data3.min_words = 600
    auto_blog_data3.max_words = 1500

    auto_blog_data3.save_to_file(filename)

    auto_blog_data4 = AutoBlog.read_from_file(filename)

    print(f"auto_blog_data4.blog_title = {auto_blog_data4.blog_title}")

    try:
        # This will raise an AttributeError exception
        auto_blog_data4.expiration_date = "soon"
    except AttributeError:
        print("AttributeError catched. We cannot add a new instance variable to auto_blog_data4.") 

The syntax is a little different since you have, for example, to use AutoBlog().blog_title instead of AutoBlog()['blog_title'] but I think it is a little bit simpler. I did not put all the error handling but it could be easily added with some additional code.
Let me know if this could suits you.

Comment by @jonrsharpe said TypedDict cannot be extended with your own methods.
This is not quite as elegant, but works fine.
I just have two functions that are not class methods.
import json
from typing_extensions import TypedDict

class AutoBlog(TypedDict):
    blog_title: str
    blog_prompt: str
    min_words: int
    max_words: int
    
def jsonToFile(item, filename):
    str_json = json.dumps(item)
    with open(filename, 'w', encoding='unicode-escape') as f:
        f.write(str_json)
def fileToJson(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        str_json = f.read()
    item = json.loads(str_json)
    return item


if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = 'c:/Users/All Users/WebsiteGarden/test_serialize.json'
    print("Filename=" + filename)

    autoBlogData1 = AutoBlog()
    autoBlogData1['blog_title'] = "my blog title"
    autoBlogData1['blog_prompt'] = "write an article about xyz"
    autoBlogData1['min_words'] = 800
    autoBlogData1['max_words'] = 1200

    jsonToFile(autoBlogData1, filename)

    autoBlogData2 = AutoBlog()
    autoBlogData2 = fileToJson(filename)
    print("autoBlogData2['blog_title']=" + autoBlogData2['blog_title'])

